# Tell Google to Refresh Search Screenshot

Tags: google, search-engines

I recently remodeled a website for a client of mine. When doing a search on Google for their website the old website is still showing as the image for the website.

Is there a way in the Google Webmaster Tools to tell Google to refresh this screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Google's Instant Preview FAQ](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-instant-previews):

> **Q: How often are previews updated?**
>
> **A:** Previews are generally updated regularly or re-generated on the fly when requested by users. In some cases, it’s possible that preview images are not updated as frequently as we normally crawl and index the page. It is not possible to manually request an update of a preview image.